# MultiValueDictKeyError Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make simple form run but I have cost, I'm not using the forms.forms of django, I'm doing the forms from HTML directly.

Well, my form simply has 1 file field and a post button, in the field I want to add an .xlsx and get data from that file and register it in a specific model but it gives me the following error:

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'ar'"
```

acontinuacion I want to show you how I have structured my code and I do not understand why I get an error, I would also like to give me an idea of ​​how to obtain the excel data that I select in the input file and register it in bd:

View:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from condominio.models import *

class TestExcel(View):
    def post (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print (request.FILES)
        file = request.FILES['ar']
        return HttpResponse('this is post')
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request ,'testing.html' ,{})
```

template :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <form action="#" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="file-field input-field">
      <div class="btn">
        <span>File</span>
        <input name="ar" id = "ar" type="file" >
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
  </form>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It is mandatory for the HTML form to have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set correctly. Otherwise the `request.FILES` will be empty. [From here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your `form` tag:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Excerpt from [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method
>   was POST and the  that posted the request has the attribute
>   enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.